# Inno Setup: Install only if not VERYSILENT

Tags: inno-setup

I would like to install and regsiter a certain file only if the setup is not run as VERYSILENT.

I don't know how I could achieve this.

My current line is

```
Source: "M:\sqlite36_engine.dll"; DestDir: {sys}; Flags: uninsneveruninstall ignoreversion
```

Can somebody tell me how this can be done?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you care about SILENT vs. VERYSILENT, or is it that you don't want to install via either type of silent?  Because if it's the latter, then you can just use `Flags: skipifsilent`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since there is still no runtime function or variable to determine if the setup is running in very silent mode, you need to make your own function to check this by iterating command line parameters. For conditional installing of a certain file we're using the [`Check`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptcheck.htm#Check) parameter, which can take such function for getting the condition by its returned value. The following script should do what you want:

```
[Files]
Source: "M:\sqlite36_engine.dll"; DestDir: {sys}; Flags: uninsneveruninstall ignoreversion; Check: not IsVerySilent

[Code]
function IsVerySilent: Boolean;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  for I := 1 to ParamCount do
    if CompareText(ParamStr(I), '/verysilent') = 0 then
    begin
      Result := True;
      Exit;
    end; 
end;
```