# Run sub-installer (very) silently when the master installer is running (very) silently

Tags: inno-setup

I have an Inno Script isntaller runs child `setup.exe` in it. I have to give silent install parameter to the `setup.exe`, when silent install parameter was given to the master installer.

Inno Script run command:

```
[Run]
Filename: "setup.exe"; Parameters:"/Install silent"; Flags: nowait
```

I gave silent installation parameter in command prompt as follows,

```
"setup location" /VERYSILENT /Install silent
```

The master Inno Setup installer is running silently, but the child `setup.exe` launched with UI.

How to get silent install parameter from command prompt in Inno Setup script file? Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Do you want to run the sub-installer silently, only if the parent installer is running silently? Or always?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, Yes, I want to run sub-installer silently while gave verysilent parameter to inno setup in command prompt. In above, gave silent installation parameter to my sub installer but UI shown. If directly given as first code snippet it works. Please suggest me "how to get parameter from command prompt".

Comment: It's what my answer shows. Did you see it? I've extended it now with distinguishing silent and very silent installations.

Answer (score 2):

There's no `/Install silent` parameter in Inno Setup.

There's `/silent` and `/verysilent`. The `/silent` still displays the installation progress window, while the `/verysilent` does not.

See [Setup Command Line Parameters](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline) in Inno Setup documentation:

> **/SILENT, /VERYSILENT**
>
> Instructs Setup to be silent or very silent. When Setup is silent the wizard and the background window are not displayed but the installation progress window is. When a setup is very silent this installation progress window is not displayed. Everything else is normal so for example error messages during installation are displayed and the startup prompt is (if you haven't disabled it with DisableStartupPrompt or the '/SP-' command line option explained above).
>
> If a restart is necessary and the '/NORESTART' command isn't used (see below) and Setup is silent, it will display a Reboot now? message box. If it's very silent it will reboot without asking.

---

So you have to run the sub-installer with the `/verysilent` flag to avoid any GUI.

```
[Run]
Filename: "setup.exe"; Parameters: "/verysilent"; Flags: nowait
```

---

Though, if you want to run the sub-installer silently, only if the parent installer is running silently, you can do it like:

```pascal
[Run]
Filename: "setup.exe"; Parameters: "{code:SilentParameter}"; Flags: nowait

[Code]

function WizardVerySilent: Boolean;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  for i := 1 to ParamCount do
    if CompareText(ParamStr(i), '/verysilent') = 0 then
    begin
      Result := True;
      Break;
    end;
end; 

function SilentParameter(Param: string): string;
begin
  if WizardSilent then
  begin
    if WizardVerySilent then
      Result := '/verysilent'
    else
      Result := '/silent';
  end;
end;
```

The code for distinguishing silent and very silent installations was inspired by [How to detect whether the setup runs in very silent mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11449561/850848) The [`WizardSilent`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_wizardsilent) is a standard function.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it works total silent:

```
[Run]
Filename: "path\setup.exe"; Parameters:/VERYSILENT; Flags: nowait

without "" in Parameter
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score -1):

We tried the same code for silently installation with inno setup

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Parameters:/VERYSILENT; Flags: nowait
```

But still getting options to select destination folder and desktop icons